# want to customise the current_user methode of devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to user `current_user` method for two purpose.

I have user gmail log in and personal  registration from site.

But `current_user` method of devise gem is not working for gmail user.

for gmail user I used below method

```
 helper_method :current_user

 def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
 end
```

kindly help me to fix this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by my self letter on.

Below code is the solution of above problem

```
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id].blank?
      devise_current_user
    else
      User.find(session[:user_id])
    end   
  end
```

This works fine for me

Comment: There's no reason to indent `current_user` definition more than `alias_method` call.